# Is there some Ansible equivalent to "failed_when" for success

Tags: linux, ansible

Looking at the documentation about error handling [Ansible error handling](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_error_handling.html)

I only see a way to fail the provisioning fail_when, i am wondering if there is any way to do the oposite.

something that looks like this:

> ```
> - name: ping pong redis
>   command: redis-cli ping
>   register: command_result
>   success_when: "'PONG' in command_result.stderr"
> ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think maybe [assert module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/assert_module.html) is what you want.

> New in version 1.5
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> - assert: { that: "ansible_os_family != 'RedHat'" }
> ```

Answer (score 15):

There seem to be no such feature, at least my suggestion on the mailing list remained unresponded:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/cIaQTmY3ZLE

What might help is to know that `failed_when` behaves differently to its semantics:

```
- name: ping pong redis
  command: redis-cli ping
  register: command_result
  failed_when: 
    - "'PONG' not in command_result.stderr"
    - "command_result.rc != 0"
```

will *not* fail if return code is 0 and there is no 'PONG' in stderr.
So it passes if any of the list is `False`

Comment: Worth noting that you can also always just wrap any boolean expression in parens and prefix it with "not" to get the same effect. For example, `not (url | matches('http://example.com/.*'))`. Pointing that out since it's sort of hidden here because you're using inline `not in` and `!=`, whereas generally there aren't special inline operators.