# Ansible: simulating a "passed when" module

Tags: error-handling, module, ansible

Ansible provides a `failed_when` module, allowing users to specify certain fail conditions on their tasks, e.g. a certain string being found in stdout or stderr.

I am trying to do the opposite: I'd like my tasks *not* to fail if any of a set of strings is found in stdout or stderr. In other words, I'd like something approaching the functionality of a `passed_when` module.

- I still want it to pass normally when the return code is 0.
- But if it would fail (rc != 0) then it should first check for the occurrence of some string.
- I.e. if some string is found it passes no matter what.

My reasoning goes like this:

> There are many reasons why the task could
>   fail - but some of these, depending on the output, I do not consider
>   as a failure in the current context.

Does anybody have a good idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look here:

[Is there some Ansible equivalent to "failed_when" for success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796110/is-there-some-ansible-equivalent-to-failed-when-for-success)

```
- name: ping pong redis
  command: redis-cli ping
  register: command_result
  failed_when: 
    - "'PONG' not in command_result.stderr"
    - "command_result.rc != 0"
```

- will not fail if return code is 0 and there is no 'PONG' in stderr.
- will not fail if there is "PONG" in stderr.

So it passes if any of the list is False

Comment: I thought the `fail_when` list gets or-linked? I.e. the task would fail if `command_result.rc != 0` is true (which is the normal behavior)?

Comment: No, that is what i wrote into the referenced ticket (just have a look at my mail conversation with mp dehaan). It is semantically very odd... It will fail if command_result.rc != 0 and there is no "PONG" in command_result.stderr

Comment: can you point me where things like `command_result.rc` are defined ?

Comment: `register: command_result`

Every module returns values. The command module returns among others `rc`, see here:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables

Answer (score 2):

Your original question was phrased like this (using boolean logic to make it easier):

> Succeed a command if a set of strings is found in stdout or stderr

Rephrasing your logic:

**fail if a set of strings is NOT found** in stdout or stderr. Using this logic it's easy to do with failed_when. Here's a snippet:

```
---
- name: Test failed_when as succeed_if
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: "'succeed_if' set of strings in stdout"
      command: /bin/echo succeed1
      register: command_result
      failed_when: "command_result.stdout not in ['succeed1',]"

    - name: "'succeed_if' set of strings in stdout (multiple values)"
      command: /bin/echo succeed2
      register: command_result
      failed_when: "command_result.stdout not in ['succeed1', 'succeed2']"

    - name: "'succeed_if' set of strings in stderr (multiple values)"
      shell: ">&2 /bin/echo succeed2 "
      register: command_result
      failed_when: "command_result.stderr not in ['succeed1', 'succeed2']"

    - name: "'succeed_if' set of strings in stderr (multiple values) or rc != 0"
      shell: ">&2 /bin/echo succeed2; /bin/false"
      register: command_result
      failed_when: "command_result.stderr not in ['succeed1', 'succeed2'] and command_result.rc != 0"

# vim: set ts=2 sts=2 fenc=utf-8 expandtab list:
```

Also the documenation you are probably looking for are [Jinja2 Expressions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#expressions)

Comment: The problem is: I still want it to pass normally when the return code is 0. But if it would fail (rc!=0) then it should first also check for the occurence of some string.

Comment: Just add the corresponding condition (see the last example...)